# ClientWebSocket and Unit Tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, websocket

I'm using `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` in a .NET 4.7 application and are facing problems when trying to make code that depends on it testable. `ClientWebSocket` is a sealed class thats defines two members (`Options`and `ConnectAsync`) that aren't part of the abstract base class `WebSocket`. Hence, I cannot mock `ClientWebSocket` nor use `WebSocket`, making unit tests basically impossible.

I'm wondering if anyone either knows an alternative web socket client for .NET that is mockable (i.e. just a very thin object adapter for `ClientWebSocket` would be enough) or any other feasible way of testing code that depends on `ClientWebSocket`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the WebSocket in the interface you need, and then mock that interface instead

Example with abbreviated method signatures:

```cs
public interface IWebSocket
{
    Task<string> ReceiveDataAsync(...);
    Task SendDataAsync(...);
    Task CloseAsync(...);

    // Add all other methods you need from the client of the websocket
}
```

Then implement an adapter:

```cs
public class WebsocketAdapter : IWebSocket
{
    private readonly WebSocket _websocket

    public WebsocketAdapter(Websocket websocket)
    {
        _websocket = websocket;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReceiveDataAsync(...)
    {
        return await _websocket.ReceiveDataAsync(...);
    }

    public async Task SendDataAsync(...)
    {
        return await _websocket.SendDataAsync(...);
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync(...)
    {
        return await _websocket.CloseAsync(...);
    }
}
```

Now you can mock your own `IWebSocket` interface in your tests.

This is called a [Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html), an object that merely wraps another object or a static method call, so you can hide it behind a mockable interface.

Comment: This humble object is exactly (actually quite literally) what I ended up with back then. Marked this as answer. :)